# Centos 7 backup script cron issue

Tags: cron, centos7, sendmail

I have found a great script to create a full Centos 7 backup daily:

```
First, log in as root and create a directory where our backups will land:

mkdir /backups

Now, we will create the following shell script file and open it for editing:

mkdir ~/bin;vi ~/bin/mybackup.sh

Put in the following content, replacing /backups in the environment variable DEST and SOURCE with the one you would like to backup as well as the recipient’s EMAIL:

#!/bin/bash
SBJT="cron backup report for `hostname -s` from $(date +%Y%m%d:%T)"
FROM=root@domain
EMAIL=johndoe@internet.com
SOURCE=/root
DEST=/backups
LFPATH=/tmp
LF=$LFPATH/$(date +%Y%m%d_%T)_logfile.log
rsync --delete --log-file=$LF -avzq $SOURCE $DEST
(echo "$SBJT"; echo; cat $LF ) | sendmail -f $FROM -t $EMAIL

Make the script executable:

chmod a+x /root/bin/mybackup.sh

Now, open crontab using:

crontab -e

Next, create the following entry by adding the following line to the end of the document, then save and close it:

30 20 * * * /root/bin/mybackup.sh
```

If I start the script manually with `/root/bin/mybackup.sh` it works fine, but via cron

```
MAILTO=johndoe@internet.com
30 20 * * * /root/bin/mybackup.sh
```

it sends an odd mail with error `/root/bin/mybackup.sh: line 9: sendmail: command not found` and the backup is not made. I don't undestand, because when I enter `echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v johndoe@internet.com` I receive the mail in my inbox.

Answer (score 0):

The PATH of `cron` is much more restricted then the ordinary user. Add as second line in your script something like:

```
source /path/to/johndoe/.bashrc
```

if the script is run by `johndoe`. Or if its run by `root` change the path

Comment: Thanks @Romeo Ninov for your help. I have added `source /root/.bashrc` as second line in `/root/bin/mybackup.sh`, but it still give the sendmail error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Sjors, do you have `sendmail` installed? Have you try just to use `mail`

Comment: I have changed `sendmail -f $FROM -t $EMAIL` to `mail -s $FROM $EMAIL` and the error is gone. I was assuming that sendmail was installed, because the manual backup was working and also the testmail was sent.

Comment: @Sjors, maybe (because of odd reason) `sendmail` is not in the PATH